# Subscribe to xamarin map/Geolocator event when the user's current location changes

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maps

I'm creating a xamarin app using xamarin.forms.maps and wanted to know if there is a way to subscribe to an event that tells me when the user's current location changes. I can get the user's current location via the geolocator plugin but I want an event-driven way to update the current location when the user moves since I want to save the user's current location to a DB when they move x meters. I've searched high and low and was not able to find what I'm really looking for. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who might come across this,

Geolocator has an event called PositionChanged that can be subscribed to in the PCL. Sadly enough it was easy to find when I was looking at the code.

Comment: Do you mean the Geolocation Xamarin Essentials API? I can't find the PositionChanged() function. I looked here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.geolocation?view=xamarin-essentials

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of samples available in the official documentation.

As for instance, you can subscribe to location updates in `Xamarin.Android` by subscribing to `FusedLocationProviderClient.RequestLocationUpdatesAsync` as read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/location#subscribing-to-location-updates). You can also use the `LocationService`, but as mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/location#using-the-android-location-service-api), this service is both an older API and is best used for devices which do not have Google Play Services installed.

You can find a sample of using the `FusedLocationProviderClient` [here](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/google-services/Location/LocationUpdates) and another sample using the `LocationService` [here](https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples/tree/master/BackgroundLocationDemo).

For iOS, you can subscribe to the `CLLocationManager.LocationsUpdated` event as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-walkthroughs/location-walkthrough). You can find a sample of this [here](https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples/tree/master/BackgroundLocationDemo).

You can then, as for instance, create your own, `ILocationManager`which is implemented platform specifically to listen for location updates in your PCL project.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Your answer is great but I found an event from the geolocator plugin that's better suited for my request.